# How does a mouse driver move the mouse pointer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouse-cursor

This might be kind of a strange question, but how does the software for a mouse work? (specifically on OSX)

If I want to move the mouse around on OSX, I've been using this code:

```
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(0);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(point); // point is of type NSPoint
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (1);
```

But this causes the cursor to jump (and even lag occasionally). How does a mouse (or trackpad) make it so fluid? What APIs do they use?

Likewise, if I use this code to move the cursor over the dock, for example, the dock doesn't magnify (magnification is turned on), even though moving the cursor there normally using the trackpad works just fine. Why?

Comment: Do you want to simulate user mouse movements (with all effects on the UI this might trigger) or do you want to know how the OS actually tracks, handles  and dispatches mouse events?

Comment: @Thilo I'd like to simulate it, but as you said, with all the UI effects and changes it triggers, as the code I posted above simulates it, but only works sometimes and doesn't trigger all the UI changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question should really be "How does a mouse *device driver* work?"

You should take a look at [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000011-CH204-TPXREF101), especially the [HID family](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Families_Ref/Families_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000021-BABFEIAC).

If you just want to simulate a mouse movement, you could also try creating a mouse event with [`CGEventCreateMouseEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCFCJGH), then posting it with [`CGEventPost`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCEDCEA).